# How do I load data from an external URL using JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dom

I want to display a name from this url http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json/

Here is my code,

```
var astrosAPI = "http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json/";

$.getJSON(astrosAPI, function (json) {
    var name = json.results[0].formatted_name;
    console.log('Name : ', name);
});
```

I want to display it with my `h3` tag. I'm new to JSON and jQuery. I keep getting

```
index.html:631 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined error
```

Comment: Take a look at JSON.parse() method, this will convert your json into an object

Comment: json clearly doesn't have a `results` property.

Comment: @SeanT that is simply not useful, and incorrect/misleading. `json` in this case will not be json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the [`success()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) or [`done()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) function.

```
var url = "http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json/";
$.getJSON(url).success(function (json) {
  var name = json.people[0].name
  console.log('Name : ', name)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are able to reach out to the specific endpoint and not be blocked by CORS it must be the format of the data.

Looking at the data, there is no property called `results` in your data.  Try debugging that line to see the proper format of the variable `json`.  It may be a `string` and you would need to call `JSON.parse(json);` in order to format it properly as an object.

You should be able to do:

```
var astrosAPI = "http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json/";

$.getJSON(astrosAPI, function (json) {
    var name = json.people[0].name;
    console.log('Name : ', name);
});
```

Comment: Thank you it works now. How do I display the name to my h3 tag. I tried         <h3 id="name"> </h3>

Comment: I figured how to convert the string to an object. $('#name').text(name);